# How to split a string by spaces and remove non-ASCII characters?

Tags: python, algorithm, ascii, list-comprehension

When I am given a string like `"Ready[[[, steady, go!"`, I want to turn it into a list like this: `[Ready, steady, go!]`.  Currently, the best I could do are two list comprehensions but I couldn't figure out a way to combine them.

```
text_list = [i for i in text.split()]
output: ['Ready[[[,', 'steady,', 'go!']

clean_list = [x for x in list(text) if x in string.ascii_letters]
output: ['R', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'y', 's', 't', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'y', 'g', 'o']
```

`clean_list` does succeed in removing non-ASCII letters but literally turns every single character into a list element.  `text_list` keeps the format intact but does not remove non-ASCII characters.  How do I combine the two logics to give me the output that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re, string
# filter out all unwanted characters using regex
pattern = re.compile(f"[^{string.ascii_letters} !]")
filtered = pattern.sub('', "Ready[[[, steady, go!")
# split
result = filtered.split()
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation would improve the quality of the answer.